# transfer my own app from device to xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have built an ios app which I have tested successfully on my ios device. Since last build Ive had to rebuild my laptop and as such Ive lost my xcode project. Is there a way I can transfer the app from my device back into xcode?

Comment: Use a data recovery tool on your mac and you can recover your deleted project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that´s not possible to do... Next time use Source Control such as [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) for example to keep track of your code and prevent this happening in the future (that´s one of many benefits of source control).

Answer (score 4):

The way you are getting your thing is totally different. However you can recover some part of your project data like images, what framework you have used etc.

First you need to connect your device with your system, then open iTunes and select your app then download that app. Now you have to click on that app see option for Show In Finder and click it

If you see your .ipa file, then make it a zip of it and then unzipped it, a payload name folder will appear on your screen. you will see appName.app, right click on it and select show package contents. This will show the app package contents. You can recover few data from that. But if you are thinking to recover code level data then it is not possible.

And you need to make a backup of your project whenever you make any updations so that any accident happened does not affect your main project.